# linq.sum is rounding

Tags: linq, sum, rounding

I have the following line in my vb.net website:

```
totCost = outstandingTimesheet.ClaimLines.Sum(Function(x) x.TotalLineCost And x.Queried = False)
```

The sum is bring rounded though and I can't work out why...

Any ideas?

I don't believe it is just a case of formatting the output it is more what is going on within the sum.

Is that correct?

Comment: What is the type of `ClaimLines`? What is the actual result? What is the expected result?

Comment: You're summing a bunch of booleans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you maybe mixing up `Where` and `Sum`? I'd suggest:

```
outstandingTimesheet.ClaimLines.Where(x => !x.Queried).Sum(x => x.TotalLineCost);
```

You are summing up the result of a bitwise and-operation:

```
outstandingTimesheet.ClaimLines.Sum(x => (x.TotalLineCost & x.Queried));
```

However, your results should be totally wrong, not just rounded. This is all C#, as I'd be horribly wrong with VB.NET. Sorry for that.

In VB.NET (by Simon):

```
totCost = outstandingTimesheet.ClaimLines.Where(Function(x) x.Queried = False).Sum(Function(x) x.TotalLineCost)
```

Comment: Or maybe he is just storing a double in an int ... hence the round up

Comment: Yeah, @Simon of what type is `totCost`?

Comment: totCost = outstandingTimesheet.ClaimLines.Where(Function(x) x.Queried = False).Sum(Function(x) x.TotalLineCost)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that you are storing a result that comes out as a double, inside an int ? 
It is possible if you havent activated the `Option strict` in your project properties. 
That would result in rounding the result of your sum.

Or you could just be wrong in your LINQ also, as stated by Mudu

Edit : To clarify the `Option strict` : if it isnt enable, implicit casts will be done without notifying by a warning or error, so it could cast a double to an int, without telling you you are doing so.

[Option strict and option explicit on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329)

Comment: Dont forget to choose an answer so that people know you have found a solution :)